# UIApplicationDelegate question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios4, xcode4

In my AppDelegate I have a reference to an NSObject like this:

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    MyObjectManager * myObjectManager;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;

@property (nonatomic, retain) MyObjectManager * myObjectManager;
```

I want to access this from my UIViewController, so I do this:

```
MyAppDelegate * appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
MyObjectManager * myObjectManager = appDelegate.myObjectManager;
maMyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[[appDelegate myObjectManager] findMyStuff:5 foundArray:maMyArray];
//[myObjectManager findMyStuff:5 foundArray:maMyArray];
```

However, I think I am not understanding the syntax in Objective C correctly because I throw an exception, EXC_BAD_ACCESS.   When I look at the values, they seem correct.

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize myObjectManager somwhere:

```
myObjectManager = [[MyObjectManager alloc] init];
```

The best place is probably in the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method.

Don't forget to release it in the dealloc.

Comment: I do, in MyAppDelegate.  I do this: MyObjectManager = [[MyObjectManager alloc] initWithContentsOfSQLiteDB:@"MyDB.sql"];  Do I have to do someting else?

Comment: Oh, I see, ok, but then where do I call my init to do things I need to do?  Can I call [[self alloc] init] in my init function?

Comment: Your code should also work fine as long as that is myObjectManager =, not MyObjectManager =.  If you put a break point right before the findMyStuff: method call does myObjectManager point to anything?

Comment: You don't call alloc in init-- but you can call other init messages you need.

Comment: In your init funtion for MyObjectManager normally you would have something like 'self = [super init];' and 'return self;'

Comment: Yes, it is: myObjectManager = [[MyObjectManager alloc] initWithContentsOfSQLiteDB:@"MyDB.sql"];  TYPO!!!  Ok, so you set me on a better path... thank you. But it does bring a new question... in my init I access another property called databasePath, which is set in my init method.  That is one of the first things called from MyAppDelegate.  I have databasePath defined as follows: @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * databasePath; in MyObjectManager.h.  databasePath seems to be random junk.

Answer (score 2):

Where is the code that allocates a MyObjectManager  and assigns it to your myObjectManager property?

Until you do that, it's nil.

Comment: In MyAppDelegate... other comment.